# How to filter an Object in Swift to only show its values?

Tags: arrays, swift, object, filter, model

I have created a model to store data about a song. On a view controller I want to only show songs by a particular artist instead of showing all the songs stored in the database.

I have tried using map and filter but didn't understand it fully, is there another method I could try?

```
let selectedArtist = artists[indexPath.row]
```

The code above is the selected the artist which is taken from the didSelect method when choosing which artist they want to display songs by. It has the type of the model - Song which holds song, artist, album.

When clicking on the selected artist, I expect the model to be filtered to only show songs by the chosen artist. This will be stored in an array matching the model or stored in an array called selectedSongs which are added to the array when being filtered matching the artist name.

Comment: "I have tried using map and filter but didn't understand it fully," You should probably try understanding it then. Anyway, 1. what's wrong with your current code? 2. Can you show the `Song` type? 3. Why is `selectedArtist` a `Song`? Shouldn't it be `Artist` or `String` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming two types, Song and Artist

```
 struct Song {
    var title: String
    var artist: Artist
    var album: String
}

struct Artist {
    var name: String
}
```

Then in the view controller you can have an array filteredSongs and a function that performs the filtering

```
class ExampleViewController {
    var songs = [Song]()
    var filteredSongs: [Song]?

    func filterSongs(byArtist artist: Artist) {
        filteredSongs = songs.filter { song in
            song.artist.name == artist.name
        }
    }
    //...
}
```

so you can then use it by doing

```
let selectedArtist = artists[indexPath.row]
filterSongs(byArtist: selectedArtist)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Currently I only have one type which is Song and that holds everything. Would that still work?

Comment: @blackers yes of course. Assuming artist is a string you can change the type in my example and replace artist.name with artist

Comment: Thank you very much that works, although I have come across a problem. On load of the View Controller I need all the artists name to be displayed but I have several songs by one artist so need to filtered the artist names so they only appear once. How can I do this please?